# Chrome and IE 9 get value = "on" from radio button when it has value=""

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have the next problem, I have three radio button like this

```
<td >
 <input type="radio" name="something" value="S">Hello World!
 <input type="radio" name="something" value="N">Good bye!
 <input type="radio" name="something" checked="checked"> Good Afternon
</td>
```

The last one radio button has not a value, but in Firefox this value has an empty string, but in Chrome or IE 9 they put the value "on" instead of ""

Anyone know this bugs?

Bye!

Comment: Every component has a default value .. so, chrome+IE bug or firefox bug ?? ..

Comment: Hi matzone, I think this is a problem with IE and Chrome, becouse in firefox I get an empty string when the last one radio button (Good Afternon) was sending, but in Chrome and IE I get the value "on"

Comment: Might be it came from  `checked="checked"`

Comment: For the record, I think the reason behind default value is to indicate that *something* was selected, as empty value would mean "no button was checked". So it's not browser bug it's by design.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know this bug, but thanks for sharing.
Maybe you can write a letter to IE or Chrome?
In the meantime however, you may want to consider adding a default value to your radio button or maybe even a space like " ", then Trim it out on your code page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to change the value="" for value="whatever character". Thank, for your reply. Best regards!